# decltype and scope resolution operator inside a function template

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, decltype

Apparently, the following code does not compile on gcc 4.7:

```
#include <vector>

struct foo {
    std::vector<int> x;

    template<typename T>
    void bar(T) {
        decltype(x)::value_type y;
    }
};

int main() {
    foo f;
    f.bar(0);
}
```

The compilation error is the following:

```
test.cpp:8:9: error: need ‘typename’ before ‘decltype (((foo*)this)->foo::x)::value_type’ because ‘decltype (((foo*)this)->foo::x)’ is a dependent scope
```

I know the solution to the problem, but why is it not compiling? `x` here is not a dependent name, so why do I need to explicitly indicate that `decltype(x)::value_type` is a type if the compiler can already figure that out by himself? Or am I wrong and `x` is actually a dependent name here?

Comment: [Compiles on 4.8.0](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=65b30a01f0a6cbe169a40d2b77afb5ba-e54ee7a04e4b807da0930236d4cc94dc). There's most of your answer. Guess it was fixed.

Comment: @chris oh damn. I tried LWS but hasn't been working for ages.

Comment: Oh hey, it's actually up again now. I've liked Coliru better for C++ since the  feedback started getting implemented.

Comment: @chris: You mean, LWS? It's still down for me

Comment: Yep, still down for me as well.

Comment: @AndyProwl, Oh, I was thinking it's been doing that other page content it sometimes has and that this would be resolved decently quickly :p I'm too optimistic sometimes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Until someone finds a specific report on this (I tried looking and the closest I've found is [this](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=49823)), this [does compile with GCC 4.8.0](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=65b30a01f0a6cbe169a40d2b77afb5ba-e54ee7a04e4b807da0930236d4cc94dc). Based on that information and my prior suspicions, I would say this is just a bug in GCC 4.7 that was fixed for 4.8.